# Number of pattern occurences in regular expression as replace variable

Tags: regex

I have the following expression:

```
echo '    <p>'.$variable.'</p>'.PHP_EOL;
```

and need regular expression which would replace it with:

```
echoln(4,'<p>'.$variable.'</p>');
```

4 represents the number of prefixing blanks (arbitrary). Problem here is how to count the number of prefixing blanks (4) and use that count as a parameter in replace string.

I tried searching with:

```
echo '([ ]*)(.*)'\.PHP_EOL;
```

and use replace string:

```
echoln($1,'$2');
```

But instead of blanks here in first place, I need the number of (occurrences of) blanks.

Comment: Regex itself cannot count the captured value length, you need a programming language to do that. Unless you use several regexps with predefine group pattern length which will be reflected in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Thx @Wiktor, I see that you're the regex guru. Maybe I was not precise. I don't need here the captured value length. I'm searching here for blanks `[ ]*` and need the number of occurrences of blanks.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean: you can't "convert" `aaaa` into `4` with a mere regex and a string replacement pattern. You can easily do that with Python, C#, Ruby.... but with a piece of code.

Comment: What the heck is `echoln()`?

Comment: What programming language is this regex question for? PHP? Add your language as a tag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, I see that you're the guru for regex and I believe you that there's no regex expression returning the number of occurrences of pattern inside target string. Then I will have to do the job using several regex search/replace actions with different prefixing blank lengths.

Comment: Or write a simple Perl script to do that quickly for you.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus echoln() is my own function replacing standard PHP echo function prefixing string with some blanks (to align code inside HTML page) and ending it with CR (PHP_EOL). I'd like to write my old expressions like `echo ('    <p>...</p>).PHP_EOL;` using new `echoln()` function. So I'd like to change all of them with my IDE's regex editor. I know how to replace strings in programming language but here I'd like to change it with regex. I thought that regex maybe has some trick with returning the number of occurrences of pattern in string (e.g sth like #$1) but it seems that's not the case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, perl, huh, I was usigng perl maybe 20 years ago, nice memories ;-) However I can do my job with several regexes actions searching `echo '  (.*)'\.PHP_EOL;` and replacing with `echoln(2,'$1');` then  searching `echo '    (.*)'\.PHP_EOL;` and replacing with `echoln(4,'$1');` and so on but that I wanted to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're already using PHP, you could use a PHP script to do the replacement, using `preg_replace_callback` to allow you to compute the length of the spaces and insert that into the replacement:

```
$text = 'echo \'    <p>\'.$variable.\'</p>\'.PHP_EOL;';

echo preg_replace_callback("/echo\s+'(\s*)(.*)'\s*\.\s*PHP_EOL;/", function ($m) {
    return "echoln(" . strlen($m[1]) . ", '$m[2]');";
}, $text);
```

Output:

```
echoln(4, '<p>'.$variable.'</p>');
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UG0KN)